# Move head with 'mouse look'

Tags: java, c#, controller, unity-game-engine

So i need a sort of hybrid first person - third person controller for multiplayer game that me and my friend are making we want to have the first person experience while having other players see a body and not a blob that is the first person controller. but i am having bugs with the mouse being able to look through the characters face, i was wondering if there was a way the have the camera move with the body, Head looking up and down.
does anyone have the code for that.

- DETAILS

We have the camera attached to the camera head which is a child object of the controller that has some of the scripts for the multiplayer in it.

The controller is the third person controller with all of the first person scripts attached to it.

CODE 'MOUSE LOOK' C# (as requested)

---

```
/// MouseLook rotates the transform based on the mouse delta.
/// Minimum and Maximum values can be used to constrain the possible rotation

/// To make an FPS style character:
/// - Create a capsule.
/// - Add the MouseLook script to the capsule.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookX. (You want to only turn character but not tilt              it)
/// - Add FPSInputController script to the capsule
///   -> A CharacterMotor and a CharacterController component will be automatically added.

/// - Create a camera. Make the camera a child of the capsule. Reset it's transform.
/// - Add a MouseLook script to the camera.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookY. (You want the camera to tilt up and down like     a head. The character already turns.)
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;

public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;

public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;

float rotationY = 0F;

void Update ()
{
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
    {
        float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") *     sensitivityX;

        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    }
    else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}

void Start ()
{
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?  You've tagged both java and C#...

Comment: Regardless of the language, your question is very broad, perhaps too broad. Where's your code? What part of your code *specifically* are you having trouble with? Your question appears to be in essence, `"...does anyone have the code for that..."`, and that's not how this site works.

Comment: You state, `"but i am having bugs with the mouse being able to look through the characters face..."` -- best if you describe your bugs, show your pertinent code, and work from there.

Comment: sorry, will do in the future. Have updated post with code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a rigged character with all rigging and all, make it the child of ur capsule and disable the mesh off the capsule.....on Calling movement function call function to animate it and ur good to go!